# Empty result with foreach() as $varialble

Tags: php, sql

I get an empty result with sql query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY performanta_cpu DESC LIMIT";

<select name="intern_memorie" id="intern_memorie"/>
<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $linie)
        {

    print '<option value="'.$linie["performanta_cpu"].'">'.$linie["performanta_cpu"].'</option>'; }
```

Same code worked few days ago!

Comment: I think $dbh->query() return link to result, but not array result

Comment: Echo out our `$sql` variable with your query and try running that in PHP myAdmin if you have it available and check the error it returns.

Comment: `print` or `echo` are same think, `print` it has an plus because it returns `1` and is a very tiny slower than echo.

Comment: It works, i forgot about limit set, how Domuta Marcel said. My wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to set `LIMIT`

so your correct query is `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY performanta_cpu DESC LIMIT 10";` or instead of 10 any number.

Comment: Oo yes thats it thanks Domuta Marcel